# ListView does not display new source

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have a ListView and I set the source at runtime. But its not displaying the new source, in other words, it does not "refresh" to show the new source:

```
private List<Item> items = new List<Item>();

  private void _LoadItems() {
                this.lvItems.ItemsSource = this.items;
                MessageBox.Show(this.items.Count + "");
            }
        }
```

This is the XAML for the listview:

```
<ListView Margin="0" Name="lvItems" SelectionChanged="lvItems_SelectionChanged">
     <ListView.View>
         <GridView>
             <GridViewColumn Header="Description" Width="400" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Description}" />
             <GridViewColumn Header="Unit Price" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding UnitPrice}" />
             <GridViewColumn Header="Quantity" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Quantity}" />
         </GridView>
     </ListView.View>
 </ListView>
```

Why is it not refreshing to show the new source when I set it via                     `this.lvItems.ItemsSource = this.items;`?

Also `MessageBox.Show(this.items.Count + "");` shows that the itemsource have changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the right way to do it is to define an `ObservableCollection` property instead of `List` that will hold the data like so :

```
 private ObservableCollection<String> _items;
        public ObservableCollection<String> Items
        {
            get
            {
                return _items;
            }

            set
            {
                _items = value;

            }
        }
```

and bind the `itemSource` of your ListsView to That collection :

```
<ListView Margin="0" Name="lvItems" SelectionChanged="lvItems_SelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Description" Width="400" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Description}" />
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Unit Price" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding UnitPrice}" />
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Quantity" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Quantity}" />
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
```

now in LoadItms fill that collection unstead,

Answer (score 0):

I can set the source when the form loads and am able to update it from my code behind file. I'm posting the XAML and code behind from my test project just in case it may help you:

My XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Click="Button_Click">Set</Button>
        <ListView Margin="0" Grid.Row="1" Name="lvItems">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Description" Width="400" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Description}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Unit Price" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding UnitPrice}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Quantity" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Quantity}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LoadItems0();

        }

        private void LoadItems0()
        {

            var items = new[]{
                 new{
                     Description = "Des1",
                     UnitPrice = "1"
                 }
             };

            this.lvItems.ItemsSource = items;
        }

        private void _LoadItems()
        {

            var items = new[]{
                 new{
                     Description = "Des1",
                     UnitPrice = "1"
                 },
                 new{
                      Description = "Des2",
                     UnitPrice = "2"
                 },
                 new{
                     Description = "Des3",
                     UnitPrice = "3"
                 },
             };

            this.lvItems.ItemsSource = items;
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _LoadItems();
        }
    }
}
```